# Matrix as element of a dataframe in R

Tags: r, list, matrix

I have an lapply function that iterates over a list of elements. For each element, the result is a matrix. Based on the list of elements and the list of matrixes, I would like to return a list of dataframes of the form

```
element1, matrix1
element2, matrix2
...
...
elementn, matrixn
```

Example:

```
e <- list(1,2)
r <- lapply(e, function(x) matrix(ncol = x, nrow = x))
```

I would like to get a list with these elements

```
(1, matrix(1x1))
(2, matrix(2x2))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can construct data frames in the `lapply` function, with `I(list(...))` which can wrap the matrix as one element in the data frame:

```
r <- lapply(e, function(x) data.frame(element = x, mat = I(list(matrix(ncol = x, nrow = x)))))
```

This gives a list of data frames:

```
r
# [[1]]
#   element mat
# 1       1  NA

# [[2]]
#   element          mat
# 1       2 NA, NA, ....
```

You can rbind the result together with `do.call(rbind, ...)`:

```
do.call(rbind, r)
#   element          mat
# 1       1           NA
# 2       2 NA, NA, ....
```